# Looping through Curl response with php and pulling information out

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm very new to coding and am studying CURL responses. My task is to loop through the results and list the "ORGANISATION_NAME" only.

My effort is this, but clearly fails and I'm not sure why.

Can someone guide me on how to do this with a simple explanation please?

```
foreach ($response[] as $key => $value) {
  echo $value['ORGANISATION_NAME'];
}
```

And this is the data.

```
[
  {
    "ORGANISATION_ID": 59931111,
    "ORGANISATION_NAME": "Low Level Repository"
  },      {
    "ORGANISATION_ID": 59931112,
    "ORGANISATION_NAME": "The Bike Shed"
  },      {
    "ORGANISATION_ID": 59931113,
    "ORGANISATION_NAME": "Taxi's are us"
  },      {
    "ORGANISATION_ID": 59931114,
    "ORGANISATION_NAME": "The apple tree"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for starters that response looks like JSON, So you need to decode it.

Also I'm not quite sure whats going on with your foreach loop, try this:

```
foreach(json_decode($response) as $item){

echo $item->ORGANISATION_ID; // Returns the value for the object
echo $item->ORGANISATION_NAME;

}
```

If you are not ready for objects you can return and associative array using json decode by setting the second parameter to true:

```
foreach(json_decode($array, true) as $item){

echo $item['ORGANISATION_ID'];
echo $item['ORGANISATION_NAME'];

}
```

[Json_decode();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

if you plan on sending PHP arrays or Objects to JSON: [json_encode();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[PHP Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: OMG, this was my first attempt but didn't know that I had to decode it. Thank you so much for spotting that. So it looks like if it's JSON then it needs decoding before you can tap into it.

Comment: Some references would be good as I'll be sharing this page with others that have the same issue.

Comment: @JulieFreeman, That's it updated. Yes in order for most languages to understand JSON it needs to convert it to its own dictionary / Object / Array types. And the same goes vice versa. The json_encode will do the reverse. Changing PHP array to Json format.

Comment: @ Wakka, that is excellent! thank you for taking the time to explain. It really did help.

Comment: @JulieFreeman, On looping through arrays, associative arrays and objects. I'd recommend looking at the docs and experimenting with it yourself to get your head round it. You were nearly there with it but you were trying to loop a singular assoc array.

Comment: @ Wakka, Yeah i can see that now, and I'll do just that. It really is something that needs to become second nature.